# mocha with ts-node create a folder ts-node-*

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

i am currently working with mocha on tests written in typescript.

here is my mocha.opts file

```
--require ts-node/register
--watch-extensions ts
--reporter nyan
test/**/*.test.ts
```

in my package.json i have:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha"
}
```

and then I run the `npm test`

However, this command creates a folder **ts-node-b04239ff3a39df9137e32efd559f1a2935cb** in my root directory.

The strangest thing is that when I run my tests using mocha cli, this folder is not created.

```
NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/mocha
```

I would like to know what this file is and how to make it no longer appear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated folder is the ts-node cache directory.

You can change the cache directory to different folder like `/tmp/` using the `--cacheDirectory` option (or setting the `TS_NODE_CACHE_DIRECTORY` env)

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#cli-and-programmatic-options

Comment: Thx for the answer. I did not know this option :)